# Is there a module for peer to peer payments?

Tags: online-payment, drupal

Is there a Drupal module to implement peer to peer or user to user payments? (Allow people to send other people money- the same concept as Venmo)

I’m NOT looking for a checkout system, but purely a way for users to enter card details and send eachother money online. A checkout system is very different from this unfortunately.

What I’ve tried:

Drupal commerce

- Setup stripe and received keys, connected keys
- setup the rest of commerce, which enables a system with stores, products, and specifically is built around a checkout/ add product to cart paradigm.
  Looked into other modules
- no other modules that are secure appear to do this, I found multiple that are secure but are all built around the same checkout paradigm and one that looked like it might potentially work but it wasn’t covered by the security advisory (which is important to me especially when it comes to making payments, in case you’re wondering the module is stripe-payments)

More research:

- and came to the conclusion I’m somehow missing a way to do this that’s so obvious that no one cares to write about it, or there just isn’t a way to do this (which doesn’t make any sense to me given that the Drupal commerce and store/product/cart/checkout system is way more complex, and includes the functionality within it, but won’t expose just this functionality to users. They have to follow the commerce paradigm)

[in case you need more detail on features:

- user A and user B can link a credit card(s) to their account
- User A can select X amount of money, and send it to user B
- User B can select X amount of money, and send it to user A]